# JpaRepository query parameters are not getting updated dynamically

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

Query parameters are not getting updated -

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.erecruitment.app.model.user;
@Repository
public interface updatePassword extends JpaRepository<user, Long>{
        
    @Transactional
    @Modifying
    @Query(value="UPDATE user SET password=?1 WHERE username=?2",nativeQuery=true)
    int updtPassword(String password,String username);  
}
```

Result upon execution is -

```
Hibernate: 
    UPDATE
        user 
    SET
        password=? 
    WHERE
        username=?
```

I tried hardcoding the parameters like -

```
@Query(value="UPDATE user SET password='ee' WHERE username='w@g.com'",nativeQuery=true)
```

And , it worked .But , the first one not worked .Can you please take a minute in helping me , because I am not getting where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The above code looks good and worked on my local machine.

Can you please add more details about your question?

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
@Transactional
@Modifying
@Query(value="UPDATE user SET password= :password WHERE username= :username ",nativeQuery=true)
int updtPassword(@Param("password") String password,@Param("username") String username);
```

Param class to be imported:

```
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
```

Comment: This solution seems to be promising . Thanks for the response .But , I already have solved the problem . Actually , from service , I was passing username first instead of a password to updtPassword method . When I corrected it worked .